# Ошибка при запуске приложения с дебагером для отображения запросов и процессов

Tags: reactjs, backend

Всем привет.
Кто сталкивался с проблемой установки Backend-приложения (на windows)
При запуске приложения с дебагером для отображения запросов и процессов выдает ошибку:

```
строка:1 знак:20
+ set DEBUG=server:* & nodemon ./bin/www
+                    ~
Амперсанд (&) не разрешен. Оператор & зарезервирован для будущих версий. Добавьте двойные кавычки до и после амперсанда
 ("&"), чтобы передать его как строку.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

В package.json стоит команда:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "set DEBUG=server: * & nodemon ./bin/www"
  }
```

В файле db.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  HOST: '127.0.0.1',
  PORT: 27017,
  DB: 'fast-company',
}
```

Пробовал манипуляции с кавычками, много разных вариантов. В интернете на эту проблему не нашел рабочего ответа. Может кто тут подскажет?